# React-select set option values from data retrieved from an API

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I just started working with React.js and I need some help.
I am using react-select and I am stuck with pushing my real data in the option section.

My data after fetching an api that I've created:

```
const [users,setUsers] = useState([]);

React.useEffect(() =>{
    fetch('https://localhost:7094/graphql/',{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({query: defTypedsQuery})
    }).
    then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>setUsers(data.data.defTypeds))
    .then(console.log("users=",users));
}, []);
```

When I console.log the data, I can see everything I need but somehow the option attribute returns null.

React-select:

```
<Select   
options={users.map(obj => 
<option key={obj.kindd} 
value={obj.kindd}> 
{obj.name}</option>)}
placeholder="Изберете..."
isSearchable={true}
isMulti
/>
```

It doesn't return any error, but there is no option/data in the select.
Can you please help me to figure out what I am missing ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you get when you console.log users?

Comment: @HasanAli I actually get an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Select` component takes options as follows:

```
        <Select
          isClearable}
          isRtl={isRtl}
          isSearchable={isSearchable}
          name="color"
          options={[
            { value: 'ocean', label: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9', isFixed: true }]}
        />
```

As far as I can tell, there is no need for `<option/>` which you use in your code.

Comment: This is correct. The options prop takes an array but you are passing an object.

Comment: Okay but let's say I converted the object into an array, how can I map it into option={ ... ] now?

Comment: It is shown on the code snippet that I shared, I actually have an array of options (with one element)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to map the data somehow like this but still the Select is all empty :(
          `options={[
            { value: users.map(obj=>obj.kindd), label: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9', isFixed: true`
What am I missing here?

Comment: You are putting an entire array inside `value`. Each select option needs a value attribute. Maybe try a simple version without `map` then refactor.